# JDBC DB resource closing performance issues

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

we have written a stored procedure wherein we need to perform logic on huge amount of data(100000 records),we are calling this SP from java code.

Performance is fine its hardly taking 1 min for calculation.

The real issue is that its taking almost 10 minutes to close callable statement.We have used multiple cursors in SP. Also we are closing and deallocating it properly.

1. So what could be issue because of it taking so much time to just close single callable statement?
2. Also is it ok if we bypass closing callable statement code since this is single threaded java job which terminates after the SP execution instead of waiting statement to close?

Comment: I wouldn't "bypass" closing JDBC resources as they will result in a memory leak if you don't.  If you really can't solve this, I suggest adding a background task to close off these resources. I suspect the close() is taking so long it is waiting for the data to be committed.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.So what could be issue because of it taking so much time to just close single callable statement?

When you are trying to close the `statement`, jdbc also tries to close its `ResultSet` object if it exists. And in your case as you say it is very large resultset it may increase the time taken.

> 2.Also is it ok if we bypass closing callable statement code since this is single threaded java job which terminates after the SP execution instead of waiting statement to close?

IMHO, it is always better to close the `statement` object, as it may create some issues. But you may take a chance to skip as you say it is a single threaded java job

Comment: Thanks Krish . But we are not iterating through any result set in java code,but we do have multiple select statements inside SP for internal SP logic.1. So does DB creates resultsets for each select statement in SP though we are not accessing it through client(Java) code. 2 . Also is it ok if i create background thread to close that long running callable statements and allow main thread to execute with remaining work.